# How can I assign a Variant to a Variant in VBA?

Tags: vba, types, variant

*(Warning: Although it might look like one at first glance, this is **not** a beginner-level question. If you are familiar with the phrase "Let coercion" or you have ever looked into the VBA spec, please keep on reading.)*

Let's say I have an expression of type `Variant`, and I want to assign it to a variable. Sounds easy, right?

```
Dim v As Variant

v = SomeMethod()    ' SomeMethod has return type Variant
```

Unfortunately, if `SomeMethod` returns an Object (i.e., a Variant with a VarType of vbObject), [Let coercion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177257.aspx) kicks in and `v` contains the "Simple data value" of the object. In other words, if SomeMethod returns a reference to a TextBox, `v` will contain a string.

Obviously, the solution is to use `Set`:

```
Dim v As Variant

Set v = SomeMethod()
```

This, unfortunately, fails if `SomeMethod` does *not* return an object, e.g. a string, yielding a *Type Mismatch* error.

So far, the only solution I have found is:

```
Dim v As Variant

If IsObject(SomeMethod()) Then
    Set v = SomeMethod()
Else
    v = SomeMethod()
End If
```

which has the unfortunate side effect of calling `SomeMethod` twice.

Is there a solution which does *not* require calling `SomeMethod` twice?

Comment: You could change `SomeMethod` to `sub SomeMethod(var as variant): set var = xxx ...` and assign to v byref style with `SomeMethod v`

Comment: @AlexK.: Coincidentally, that's exactly what I ended up using, although for other reasons (I needed something similar to .NET's TryParse/TryGet pattern, so I had SomeMethod return a Boolean and use ByRef for the Variant). I still need to make that ugly IsObject check inside SomeMethod, which bothers me a bit, but I guess there just is no `LetSet v = ...` statement in VBA.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In VBA, the only way to assign a Variant to a variable where you don't know if it is an object or a primitive, is by passing it as a parameter.

If you cannot refactor your code so that the `v` is passed as a parameter to a Sub, Function or Let Property (despite the `Let` this also works on objects), you could always declare `v` in module scope and have a dedicated Sub solely for the purpose of save-assigning that variable:

```
Private v As Variant

Private Sub SetV(ByVal var As Variant)
    If IsObject(var) Then
        Set v = var
    Else
        v = var
    End If
End Sub
```

with somewhere else calling `SetV SomeMethod()`.

Not pretty, but it's the only way without calling `SomeMethod()` twice or touching its inner workings.

---

### Edit

Ok, I mulled over this and I think I found a better solution that comes closer to what you had in mind:

```
Public Sub LetSet(ByRef variable As Variant, ByVal value As Variant)
    If IsObject(value) Then
        Set variable = value
    Else
        variable = value
    End If
End Sub
```

> [...] I guess there just is no LetSet v = ... statement in VBA

Now there is: `LetSet v, SomeMethod()`

You don't have a return value that you need to `Let` or `Set` to a variable depending of its type, instead you pass the variable that should hold the return value as first parameter *by reference* so that the Sub can change its value.

Comment: Another syntax would be to treat `LetSet` as a (parametric) property, allowing you to do `LetSet(v) = SomeMethod()` - [see here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/231790/146810) for the code

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim v As Variant
For Each v In Array(SomeMethod())
    Exit For 'Needed for v to retain it's value
Next v
'Use v here - v is now holding a value or a reference
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use error trapping to reduce the expected number of method calls. First try to set. If that succeeds -- no problem. Otherwise, just assign:

```
Public counter As Long

Function Ambiguous(b As Boolean) As Variant
    counter = counter + 1
    If b Then
        Set Ambiguous = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Ambiguous = 1
    End If
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, b As Boolean

    Randomize
    counter = 0
    For i = 1 To 100
        b = Rnd() < 0.5
        On Error Resume Next
            Set v = Ambiguous(b)
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                v = Ambiguous(b)
            End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
    Debug.Print counter / 100

End Sub
```

When I ran the code, the first time I got 1.55, which is less than the 2.00 you would get if you repeated the experiment but with the error-handling approach replaced by the naïve `if-then-else` approach you discussed in your question.

Note that the more often the function returns an object, the less function calls on average. If it almost always returns an object (e.g. that is what it is supposed to return but returns a string describing an error condition in certain cases) then this way of doing things will approach 1 call per setting/ assigning the variable. On the other hand -- if it almost always returns a primitive value then you will approach 2 calls per assignment -- in which case perhaps you should refactor your code.

Answer (score 2):

[It appears that I wasn't the only one with this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810316/using-getmem-and-varptr-to-get-around-object-default-values?noredirect=1#comment98340983_55810316)

The solution was given to me [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?873949-How-to-set-a-variant-without-VB6-default-value).

In short:

```
Public Declare Sub VariantCopy Lib "oleaut32.dll" (ByRef pvargDest As Variant, ByRef pvargSrc As Variant)
Sub Main()
  Dim v as Variant
  VariantCopy v, SomeMethod()
end sub
```

It seems this is similar to the `LetSet()` function described in the answer, but I figured this'd be useful anyway.

Comment: The method could return a specific Object for example. You need to cast the method call to a Variant to avoid crashes: VariantCopy v, CVar(SomeMethod())

Comment: @CristianBuse really? Can you give an example of such an object? I've not experienced this previously but would like to learn what causes that crash to occurr :)

Comment: Apologies for not testing properly. I was using 'Function' instead of 'Sub' for the declaration of the VariantCopy API and I was also missing the return type (As Long) which compromises the API. Using your declaration works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim v As Variant
Dim a As Variant
a = Array(SomeMethod())
If IsObject(a(0)) Then
    Set v = a(0)
Else
    v = a(0)
End If
```