# Optional Range to Sub Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range

I've got an existing Macro I'd like to use by passing an rng argument, but if  no rng is passed, the macro asks for a rng via inputbox, but I can't get the argument to work correctly.

Here is what I have:

```
Sub Four_Hundred_Fourty_Four_Split_Sub(Optional urng)
     ' Tried (Optional urng As Range), but it didn't work, couldn't run sub without arg

If IsEmpty(urng) = False Then 'urng = Missing
    Debug.Print urng
    Set urng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
End If
```

How can I get an optional rng argument to work in this method?

Comment: You are going to have to grab that input box as a string.  Then set a Range variable using that string.  Might want to test the validity of the string before you try that, however.

Comment: Try `If urng Is Nothing Then`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using an optional argument in a procedure, you need to use `IsMissing`:

```
Sub Four_Hundred_Fourty_Four_Split_Sub(Optional urng)
    If IsMissing(urng) Then
        Set urng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
    End If
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: `urng` is passed as a `Variant` with this method. 
This may introduce bugs that are easily avoided by using `As Range`

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious `IsMissing` only makes sense in the context of `Variant`. It is always `False` for other data types.

Comment: Note that if the user presses Cancel, `Application.InputBox` is documented to return `Variant/False`, and that cannot be used with `Set`. And if you remove `Set`, then when the user does select a range, it will be let-coerced to a Variant array instead. To work around this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36898101/11683.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the range variable with nothing:

```
Sub test(Optional urng As Range)
    If urng Is Nothing Then
        Set urng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
    End If
    Debug.Print urng.Address
End Sub
```

works as expected.

Comment: Then there's no way to distinguish between `test` and `test Nothing`.

Comment: @GSerg Good point -- but it seems likely that asking the user for a range is the desired behavior if `Nothing` is explicitly passed.

Comment: When i use `Optional urng As Range` I can't run the macro without passing `urng`

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Because you also need `= Nothing` in the end.

Comment: I found that online and tried, still can't run macro without passing arg. Using `IsMissing` works perfectly. I feel stupid because I used debug and it told me that `urng = Missing` and I didn't think to test `IsMissing` lol. I did try `If urng = missing` but that didn't work.

Comment: @GSerg I am able to use this exact code (without `=Nothing` at the end) and `test` by itself works as expected both in the Intermediate window and when called by another sub.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Perhaps the problem is if you ran `test()` rather than `test`. In VBA, you don't put sub arguments in parentheses. Sometimes it is harmless, but sometimes it isn't when you actually do so.

Comment: @JohnColeman You are right; I don't know why the OP had this result then. Well, in any case both this answer and the accepted answer throw an exception if the user presses Cancel. Counter intuitively, `Set` should be removed - and then it will return the Variant array instead of the range, which I assume is the source of your original wrong test.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36898101/11683) is required to overcome.

Comment: I'm running Macro by pressing the start button inside the editor.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Then not even `= Nothing` will help. That mechanism does not support anything other than `Optional [As Variant]`. Otherwise this is perfectly callable from code.

Comment: @GSerg I had no idea the editor was limiting, I always run my code by just clicking in a macro and running via start. It works that way now, but as you said, I have it undefined aka `Variant`. I will try calling from another macro w/o an argument! I do want to learn the best/proper methods and seems community agree's this is better.

Comment: Can you post examples of calling this via code as I don't believe you are correct that this is due to me using the VBA editor to run the Macro, I think its perhaps how I am calling the test sub.

Comment: You would call it (without any argument) by simply having `test` appear all by itself in another sub. One possibility is to have two subs. The first sub would always have a range as an argument. The second sub would have no arguments, but would use `inputbox` to get a range which it then forwards to the first sub, which does the actual work. This second sub would be the one that you would e.g. attach to a button or call from the developer tab. It is not uncommon to have one sub act as an IO wrapper of another sub.